# Use class-validator Matches to validate property pattern with a regex

Tags: regex, typescript, class-validator

I wrote the following simple script:

```
let regexpNumber = new RegExp('^[+ 0-9]{5}$');

const digitStringProp1: string = '12345'
const digitStringProp2: string = '1234f'
const digitStringProp3: string = '123456'
console.log(regexpNumber.test(digitStringProp1));
// expected output: true
console.log(regexpNumber.test(digitStringProp2));
// expected output: false
console.log(regexpNumber.test(digitStringProp3));
// expected output: false


import { Matches } from 'class-validator';
export class TestClass {

    public myStringProp!: string;

    @Matches('^[+ 0-9]{5}$')
    public digitStringProp: string;

    constructor(myStringProp: string, digitStringProp: string) {
        this.myStringProp = myStringProp;
        this.digitStringProp = digitStringProp;
    }
}

const firstName = 'Johnny'
try {
  const testClass1 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp1);
  console.log(testClass1)
  const testClass2 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp2);
  console.log(testClass2)
  const testClass3 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp3);
  console.log(testClass3)

} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

And its output is:

```
true
false
false
TestClass { myStringProp: 'Johnny', digitStringProp: '12345' }
TestClass { myStringProp: 'Johnny', digitStringProp: '1234f' }
TestClass { myStringProp: 'Johnny', digitStringProp: '123456' }
```

First 3 lines are as expected, but I was expecting for failure when instantiating `TestClass` with `digitStringProp` not according to regex.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrong to assume constructor will fail.
Need to import `validate` and use as follows:

```
const testClass1 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp1);
validate(testClass1).then(errors => {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    console.log('validation failed. errors: ', errors);
  } else {
    console.log('validation succeed');
  }
})

const testClass2 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp2);
validate(testClass2).then(errors => {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    console.log('validation failed. errors: ', errors);
  } else {
    console.log('validation succeed');
  }
})

const testClass3 = new TestClass(firstName, digitStringProp3);
validate(testClass3).then(errors => {
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    console.log('validation failed. errors: ', errors);
  } else {
    console.log('validation succeed');
  }
})
```

Then output will look like:

```
true
false
false
validation succeed
validation failed. errors:  [
  ValidationError {
    target: TestClass { myStringProp: 'Johnny', digitStringProp: '1234f' },
    value: '1234f',
    property: 'digitStringProp',
    children: [],
    constraints: {
      matches: 'digitStringProp must match ^[+ 0-9]{5}$ regular expression'
    }
  }
]
validation failed. errors:  [
  ValidationError {
    target: TestClass { myStringProp: 'Johnny', digitStringProp: '123456' },
    value: '123456',
    property: 'digitStringProp',
    children: [],
    constraints: {
      matches: 'digitStringProp must match ^[+ 0-9]{5}$ regular expression'
    }
  }
]
```

see https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#usage (rtfm)